# Iterating through 3D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, 3d

I am trying to write a memory efficient code for iterating through 2 three-dimensional numpy arrays. Consider the following example:

First array is 3 dimensional for global NDVI (LAT, LON, TIME)
Second array is also 3 dimensional for global Temperature (LAT, LON, TIME).

I would want to use a function which takes two "time series" as arrays, each pixel's column for the TIME axes. The function will calculate and returen value between the two time series, and I want to iterate this function for the whole LAT-LON grid.
Currently my code looks like this, however I use array iteration in a "for" loop, that gets too memory extensive when working on global scales.

```
ndvi = np.random.rand(35, 35, 10)
temperature = np.random.rand(35, 35, 10)

lat, lon, time = stack.shape

for i in range(lat):
    for j in range(lon):
        ts_1 = []
        ts_2 = []
        for im_n in range(time):
            ts_1.append(ndvi[i][j][im_n])
            ts_2.append(temperature[i][j][im_n])
            
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts_1, ts_2)), columns=['ts_1', 'ts_2'])
        
#The next function takes two time series from the two arrays: ndvi and time along 
        gc_res = grangercausalitytests(df, 3)[3][0]['params_ftest'][1]
```

I was looking into "nditer" however, I had not much success. I would appreciate any help

Thank you!
David

I tried using a for loop to loop through two 3 dimensional arrays but too memory extensive.

Comment: There is no need to create a list and append items in it. You can create a Numpy array of shape `(n,2)` and use functions like reshape/transpose or even fill it directly with `ndvi[i,j,:]`. Pandas supports Numpy arrays. This will be much faster and use less memory. Note that `pd.DataFrame` is generally pretty slow so having in 2 nested loops often mean the resulting code will take a long time to run. Also note that `ndvi[i][j][im_n]` is less (CPU/Memory) efficient than `ndvi[i,j,im_n]`.

Comment: 1. Avoid for loops at all cost. The whole point of numpy/pandas is not to iterate them. 2. If you really have to iterate things, then, never ever have a dataframe creation inside the iteration.

Comment: Here you could create the dataframe with `pd.DataFrame({'ts_1':nvi[i,j,:], 'ts_2':temperature[i,j,:]})`. But in reality, what you need to do, is NOT doing that, and find another way to run your causality test. Ideally with a vectorized solution that can work directly on the whole `ndvi` and `temperature` arrays. But we can't help with this (tho this is what you really need), since you didn't post a [mre] and said nothing of this causality test function.

Comment: Is it possible to show the code or the logic of the function grangercausalitytests, it might can be vectorized fully with numpy.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the coments.

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.html#grangercausalitytests

This is the logic for the function.